# How do I justify $\cot 60$ being $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Apologies if this is a basic question, my trigonometry skills simply isn't nowhere near up to scratch.

I have a real problem grappling with how $\cot$ functions. At least in my limited understanding, the standard values found in most table simply doesn't reflect how the identity seems to be calculated.

Take for instance $\cot \frac{\pi}{3}$

$\sin \frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\cos \frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{1}{2}$

$\tan 60=\frac{\sin 60}{\cos 60}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{3}$

I have seen two definitions of $\cot$, $\frac{\cos}{\sin}$ and $\frac{1}{\tan}$. According to both these definitions, the value of $\cot 60$ should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Instead in [most tables](https://www.livingston.org/cms/lib9/NJ01000562/Centricity/Domain/742/calc/Trig%20functions%20chart%20-%20answers.pdf) the value is claimed to be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

Are my calculations off? Am I reading the table wrong? Or is this actually the same value, written in this way due to some kind of strange convention?

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt3}3=\frac1{\sqrt3}$. It's called "rationalization" of a surd, i.e. writing an element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt [k]n\,:\, n,k\in\Bbb N)$ as a sum of linear combinations with rational coefficients of roots of integers.

Comment: Your calculations are correct.  If you rationalize the denominator of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, you should obtain $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.  By the way, the definition $\cot\theta = \frac{1}{\tan\theta}$ is only valid when $\tan\theta \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ \sqrt{3}\ $ is defined to be the (unique*) positive real number whose square is $\ 3.\ $ We therefore have:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = 1\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\left( \sqrt{3} \right)^2} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}. $$

$$$$

Alternatively,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = 1\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{9}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}. $$

*Uniqueness is not usually a part of the definition, but it is not difficult to show that the number is unique...